# Is there a way to print out the results of a table query in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

I could have sworn I've done this before but cannot figure it out again. The context menu doesn't have a print option and I don't see one in the toolbar menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO** - just select columns - copy and paste in Excel - next print the way how you want

Comment: I'm sensing anger in this answer. I'm sorry if I offended you.

Comment: no anger at all - just have similar needs and do it this this way - viva MS

Answer (score 0):

I actually use 'Access Data Projects' for this purpose, it makes printing MUCH nicer, and then you can also copy / paste from ADP into Outlook without going through Excel.